# Access webservice using Soap in Android

Tags: soap

I'm trying to access webservice through soap.I got a response but its in array format and i can't get individual element.please help me to get out from it

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);

```
          //Use this to add parameters
           request.addProperty("CityName",txtFar.getText().toString());


          //Declare the version of the SOAP request
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            /*SoapObject result,obj1,obj2,obj3;
            int count;*/

            try {
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

                // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                SoapObject  result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;            

                if(result != null)
                {
                      //Get the first property and change the label text                    

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "before Edt", 500).show();
                    txtCel.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
                     //txtCel.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());

                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "After Edt", 500).show();
                }           
                else
                {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

          } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example code helps:

```
SoapObject result = soapConnection.sendRequest(request, METHOD);

    List<Pair<Integer, String>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer,String>>();
    for(int i=0; i<result.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
        SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(i);
        int distributorId = Integer.parseInt(soapObject.getPropertyAsString(0));
        String distributorName = soapObject.getPropertyAsString(1);
        list.add(new Pair<Integer, String>(distributorId, distributorName));
    }
```